# Redux state not updating until second dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building a weather app, and I want to use Redux to manage whether the state is Celsius or Fahrenheit. I have created a reducer that should just flip from C to F and back when called. The first time it's called, it stays on C instead of changing to F. Then the second time it's called it changes to F as it should. Please help ...

Reducer:

```
    if (action.type === 'CHANGE_SYSTEM') {
        let newSystem;
        system === 'C' ? (newSystem = 'F') : (newSystem = 'C');
        return newSystem;
    } else {
        return system;
    }
};
```

here's the action creator:

```
export const changeSystem = (sys) => {
    return {
        type: 'CHANGE_SYSTEM',
    };
};
```

and here's the code that calls the change:

```
..........
switchSystem = () => {
        this.props.changeSystem();
        console.log(this.props);
    };
...........
```

and the JSX:

```
<div className="switch" onClick={this.switchSystem}>
                            {this.displaySwitch()}
                        </div>
```

Comment: The updated props will not be available until the next render. Console logging `this.props` immediately after calling a function to update them will never yield updated results. It doesn't matter if its dispatch, or any other updater (sync or async). It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: Move your log into the `render` method and you will see them updated as expected.

Comment: Much appreciated guys!! Always good to hear that it's technically working